# React-native-ble-plx unable to read with Android version less than 9

Tags: android, react-native, android-bluetooth, react-native-ble-plx

I am using React native version "0.63.3" and "react-native-ble-plx" version "2.0.2".
I am unable to read the characteristics in Android version less than 9.

It throws an error "Disconnected from {deviceId} with status 22 (UNKNOWN)"
If I debug, I could find this in BleError.js is thrown
"Error: Unknown error occurred. This is probably a bug! Check reason property"
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was recently working on an app requiring bluetooth functionality, I found [this](https://github.com/patlux/react-native-bluetooth-state-manager) library to be much better than react-native-ble-plx, make sure to also check out [their](https://github.com/patlux/react-native-bluetooth-state-manager/tree/master/example) example to get a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: The only purpose of the library react-native-bluetooth-state-manager is to manage the Bluetooth state. Not more, not less.

If you need further functionality like connecting and communicating to a device, please look at react-native-ble-plx.

Comment: That's not true, I've used it to scan, connect to devices and disconnect from devices. Take a look at the example they have at their github.

Comment: Do you speak about the react-native-bluetooth-manager package?